# Datetime format inconsistencies in C# and jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have an issue, i have a user based datetime format setting. 
Now, i set the input format in the Global.asax as shown below

```
   void MvcApplication_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                if (userSettings.Settings.ContainsKey(Constants.DateFormat))
                {
                    CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
                    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = userSettings.Setting.Attributes[Constants.DateFormat];
                    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = userSettings.Setting.Attributes[Constants.DateFormat];
                    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = userSettings.Setting.Attributes[Constants.DateFormat];
                }
     }
```

But when i bind the date values from a UI textbox to a property, i get only null values. what am i missing in this process.

the date format that the user has given is 'dd/mm/yy'. after MVC model binding is done, the input of '01/11/12' is bound as 11th january 2012.

Kindly suggest the issue and where will the fix be working out.

**EDIT**

Is it possible only to have month as first in a dateformat string like mm/dd/yy. is it not possible to have dd/mm/yy as a format string.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID");
```

The example is taking culture from Indonesia, we use dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: I have date time format obtained from the users and have to set that value for the current culture. The sample you gave is for setting the culture info, also you cannot set the culture on a datetimepattern

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into a formal date format that can then be localized.  We chose to go with ISO 8601 (which is now the default for WebAPI).  Then, you can be confident on the client that you are going to read the correct date from the serialized format.  However, then you need to localize the time (if needed).

Scott Hanselman has a good [write up](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) of the issues.

And [this datetime javascript](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-localtime/wiki/Usage) library looks interesting.